# Generate a model for JSON with attribute of the type List and String

Tags: java, android, json, gson

thanks in advance to those who could see my publication. I'm working with services and I have the following JSON

```
"custom_attributes": [                  
        {
            "attribute_code": "meta_description",
            "value": "Calzado"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "category_ids",
            "value": [
                "2",
                "151",
                "161",
                "163"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

and what I try gives the following error if the Value attribute I place in a List.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 8375 path $.custom_attributes[0].value

model

```
public class CustomAttribute {

@SerializedName("attribute_code")
private String attributeCode;
@SerializedName("value")
private List<String> value = null;

public String getAttributeCode() {
return attributeCode;
}

public void setAttributeCode(String attributeCode) {
this.attributeCode = attributeCode;
}

public List<String> getValue() {
return value;
}

public void setValue(List<String> value) {
this.value = value;
}

}
```

Comment: What library are you using for converting JSON into POJOs?

Comment: I'm working with retrofit2

Comment: Retrofit allows you to set different converters, e.g `GSON`, `Jackson`

Comment: Please provide your model class as well, it seems you trying to parse list of strings instead of custom object

Comment: I do not know how to create a model class for this JSON, that's why my query is published. @CROSP , well I have the model like that and it gives me that error

Answer (score 1):

`"custom_attributes"` itself is an array with objects

I assume somewhere you have `List<CustomAttibute>`

and that array has no consistent object format within. `value` is both a String, and a `List<String>`.

The best you can do is `private Object value = null;`, then you must check its type and cast it later at runtime, or you can not use Retrofit w/ the Gson converter, as Gson expects consistently formed object types within lists (meaning for every JSON key, there is only one value type).

Comment: Thank you ! I was not sure about doing it that way, but I guess I should have tried before, anyway I got the result

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting means that you are telling the model to expect an array where it should be getting a string.

In order to solve your issue easily you can use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) online resource to generate your model (by just copy pasting the json file)

or you can use [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo) plugin to generate you model directly from android studio!

Hope you got your answer!

Comment: can you see that the attribute value receives first a string data then a list, how to make a model for that?, is my question.

Comment: please post the entire json or use the online tool and it will produce the model for you!